# Weka's PCA is taking too long to run

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, weka

I am trying to use Weka for feature selection using PCA algorithm.

My original feature space contains ~9000 attributes, in 2700 samples.

I tried to reduce dimensionality of the data using the following code:

```
AttributeSelection selector = new AttributeSelection();
PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents();
Ranker ranker = new Ranker();
selector.setEvaluator(pca);
selector.setSearch(ranker);
Instances instances = SamplesManager.asWekaInstances(trainSet);
try { 
    selector.SelectAttributes(instances);
    return SamplesManager.asSamplesList(selector.reduceDimensionality(instances));
} catch (Exception e ) {
            ...
}
```

However, It did not finish to run within 12 hours. It is stuck in the method `selector.SelectAttributes(instances);`.

**My questions are:**
Is so long computation time expected for weka's PCA? Or am I using PCA wrongly?

**If the long run time is expected:**

How can I tune the PCA algorithm to run *much* faster? Can you suggest an alternative? (+ example code how to use it)?

**If it is not:** 

What am I doing wrong? How should I invoke PCA using weka and get my reduced dimensionality?

**Update:** The comments confirms my suspicion that it is taking much more time than expected.

**I'd like to know**: How can I get PCA in java - using weka or an alternative library.

Added a bounty for this one.

Comment: I don't know weka, but this isn't a reasonable amount of time. PCA takes as long to run as matrix multiplication (because that's what it is, essentially).

Comment: @GuyAdini: I expected it is not reasonable, and I am misusing it. Do you know of an open source library [preferably in java] that I can use? [I'd also be happy to get a sample code how to use it]

Comment: Sorry - never did that in Java (otherwise I'd post an answer). If you want another language, try Python's sklearn. Anyway, coding PCA yourself is about 3 lines of code, given a matrix manipulation library: set S = X*X^t, then take the first k eigenvectors of S.

Comment: straightforward in MATLAB as well: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/princomp.html (to give you an idea of how much time it takes with your data)

Comment: @GuyAdini, PCA is not essentially matrix multiplication; it is a much more difficult problem. Not enough to justify 12 hours, but still.

Comment: @DonReba: How is PCA different from taking the top k (or summing the eigenvalues up to a certain threshold) eigenvectors of X'*X? I mean - you then have to project your data onto those selected vectors, but matrix multiplication is 99% of the computation.

Comment: @GuyAdini, computing those eigenvectors is the bulk of the computation. The crudest method for this involves taking a large power of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Computing that product is the bulk of the computation as it requires n matvecs (unless you want all the eigenvectors, but that never happens as the bottom few represent noise). If you compute the first k singular vectors directly most algorithms will converge well before n matvecs happen. cf http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2274

Comment: In any event, 12 hours to do PCA on a 9000 x 3000 matrix is unreasonable. I don't know how to use Weka, but the problem is somewhere in how you are calling it.

Comment: I am surprised it does not get any answer yet. If someone can think of a way to improve the question, don't hesitate to edit or ask for it in comments.

Comment: **I have no idea the question was downvoted** (and a half year after it was published). It shows research (I posted the code I used), I believe the problem is very clear (though the solution might not be), and I believe it is useful for anyone who needs to use PCA using Weka with a large feature space.

Comment: @amit i asked this to you because it seem that you have done work on text categorization please sir help me out . what should be the input for KNN Is there any open source for KNN??

Comment: @amit sir my question may not be clear but if you reply i can explain my problem  please sir help me out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After deepening in the WEKA code, the bottle neck is creating the covariance matrix, and then calculating the eigenvectors for this matrix. Even trying to switch to sparsed matrix implementation (I used [COLT](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/)'s [SparseDoubleMatrix2D](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/SparseDoubleMatrix2D.html)) did not help.

The solution I came up with was first reduce the dimensionality using a first fast method (I used information gain ranker, and filtering based on document frequencey), and then use PCA on the reduced dimensionality to reduce it farther.

The code is more complex, but it essentially comes down to this:

```
Ranker ranker = new Ranker();
InfoGainAttributeEval ig = new InfoGainAttributeEval();
Instances instances = SamplesManager.asWekaInstances(trainSet);
ig.buildEvaluator(instances);
firstAttributes = ranker.search(ig,instances);
candidates = Arrays.copyOfRange(firstAttributes, 0, FIRST_SIZE_REDUCTION);
instances = reduceDimenstions(instances, candidates)
PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents();
pca.setVarianceCovered(var);
ranker = new Ranker();
ranker.setNumToSelect(numFeatures);
selection = new AttributeSelection();
selection.setEvaluator(pca);
selection.setSearch(ranker);
selection.SelectAttributes(instances );
instances = selection.reduceDimensionality(wekaInstances);
```

However, this method scored worse then using a greedy information gain and a ranker, when I cross-validated for estimated accuracy.

Comment: Can I see the full code for this? including how to do cross validation for estimated accuracy

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using the default configuration for the PCA, which judging by the long runtime, it is likely that it is doing way too much work for your purposes.

Take a look at the options for [PrincipalComponents](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/attributeSelection/PrincipalComponents.html).

1. I'm not sure if `-D` means they will normalize it for you or if you have to do it yourself. You want your data to be normalized (centered about the mean) though, so I would do this yourself manually first.
2. `-R` sets the amount of variance you want accounted for. Default is `0.95`. The correlation in your data might not be good so try setting it lower to something like `0.8`.
3. `-A` sets the maximum number of attributes to include. I presume the default is all of them. Again, you should try setting it to something lower.

I suggest first starting out with very lax settings (e.g. `-R=0.1` and `-A=2`) then working your way up to acceptable results.

Comment: It is running for ~2 hours now with `{"-R=0.1", "-A=2"}` without success. Might also be worth mentioning: My samples are very sparse, the original samples are taken from the BOW model of comments.

Comment: This is starting to look strange. Why don't you just program it manually in MATLAB / Python (use Python's free numpy/scipy to calculate the eigenvalues), and see how long it takes? The algorithm really is two lines of code.

Comment: @amit: That is quite strange indeed. If your data is sparse, it might be worth switching to a sparse implementation of PCA which will speed it up significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The parameters were not the issue. It did not speed up the calculation (and I do not think it does, I think it only helps it to chose the number of features to be selected, but I could be wrong). I had to reduce the dimensionality using a fast method first, and then use PCA on the reduced data. I added an answer giving more details. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: FYI Link is broken. @ Nov 2016

Answer (score 1):

Best

for the construction of your covariance matrix, you can use the following formula which is also used by matlab. It is faster then the apache library.

[image]

Whereby Matrix is an m x n matrix. (m --> #databaseFaces)