# Android - Weka Classification is Taking too much time

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm, libsvm

I am using weka library for implementing classification algorithms in android, Though Weka lib is not fully compatible with android , I am using [Weka For Android](https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android) as lib in my app.
But its taking too much time for building model

Before posting this, I gone through various link, but cant get any consolidated solution

Some links are:

[Weka's PCA is taking too long to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482108/wekas-pca-is-taking-too-long-to-run)

[Using Weka classifiers on Android](http://www.pervasive.jku.at/Teaching/_2012WS/PervasiveComputingInfrastructure/Uebungen/UE04/04%20Exercise%20Realtime%20Classification.pdf)

[Android - Adding external library to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615381/android-adding-external-library-to-project)

I am using fallowing code for classification

```
OneClassClassifier classifier = new OneClassClassifier();
        classifier.setNominalGenerator(new NominalGenerator());
        classifier.setTargetClassLabel("1");
        classifier.setNumericGenerator(new DiscreteGenerator());
        classifier.setSeed(1);
        classifier.setNumRepeats(10);

        classifier.buildClassifier(train);

        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
        eval.evaluateModel(classifier, test);       



        System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n",      false));
```

This Code is working fine in my Java application. But if i put the same code in Android App, Its taking too much time say 4-6 minute for building the Model.

Please suggest some way to get out from this.
Also I am not able to serialized / deserialized model in android , while its working fine in java.

Comment: What's wrong with the links you've found? The first one seems to give a straightforward answer. Consider also asking a different question about serialization - there should be one question in one post.

Comment: Its for PCA,I have done that part, while for classification, its taking too much time

Comment: Right. Perhaps it's just running slow, because the device is slow? :) SVM's are expensive to train, even on PCs. Maybe you could switch to decision trees? Do you really need such a strong classifier?

Comment: Right Thanks for your comments , Actually I need Unary Classification,I tried One Class SVM for this, Decisions trees works on binary/multi classification.  Are there some other alogrthims which works on unary class?

Comment: No, in case of one-class classification I also heard only about SVMs. My only idea left is that maybe you could train the classifier on a stronger machine, serialize the model, and then just use it on the Android device.

Comment: Use Spark. Time to change tech!

Comment: Thanks sam, But what i read there Spark MLlib also not supports one class classification , Its Support  binary classification, regression, clustering and collaborative filtering. Can we use this as one class svm ?